# Autodelete child record on saving Parent

Tags: go, go-gorm

suppose I have following tables

```
type User struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string
    Addresses []*Address
}
type Address struct {
    ID      int
    UserID  int
    Address string
}
```

and I have 1 user with 2 addresses on DB

```
User{
  ID: 1,
  Name: "sample",
  Addresses: []*Address{
    &Address{ID: 10, UserID: 1, Address: "addr1"},
    &Address{ID: 11, UserID: 1, Address: "addr2"} // <- want to delete it
  }
}
```

If I remove the 2nd Address from User's Addresses slice and save the User entity,
the 2nd address still exists on DB...

Is there any way to delete a child on saving a Parent?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the one you are saving , updated on the same entry or created as different entry. On your remove operation for that particular user , you might need to update operation as well for that user , ie delete that address column completely and update with that one address might work. I am not familiar with gorm framework, but some operations cant be done directly in orm frameworks where we need to run explicit queries to do the same and most of the orm frameworks provides option to run db queries .